# How to use a variable into a structure of timer in Java

Tags: java, timer, delay

I don't know how to add a delay time for 10 minutes after a actionListener was executed.

I'm progaming with IntelliJ IDEA.

The code:

```java
public MainPage(){
    firstStepGroup1.addActionListener(e -> {
        familiar.setVisible(false);
        nefamiliar.setVisible(false);

        Images firstNImages;
        firstNImages = images.getFirstN(6);
        firstNImages.add(new ImageIcon());
        public int stare = 0;
        Timer timer;
        timer = new Timer(1, new ActionListener() {
            public int counter = 0;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                rightLabel.setIcon(firstNImages.get(counter));
                counter++;
                if (counter == 2) {
                    rightLabel.setText("Thank you for watching!");
                    ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    stare = 1 ;  //I can't use this variable it should be array.But I 
                                    tried and is not working
                }
            }

        });
        if(stare == 1){
            for(int i=600;i>=0;i--){
                timer.setDelay(1000);
                rightLabel.setText("Time remaining\""+i+"");
            }
        }

        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.setDelay(5000);
        timer.start();
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with your code ? why it doesn't works ?

Comment: Variable 'stare' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be final or effectively final.

Comment: And if a put final the error is :

Comment: Cannot assign a value to final variable 'stare'